# How to use underscore template tag from a backbone model?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have a very small simple time app using json from an api http://date.jsontest.com/

Essentially everything works except calling the json value inside the template from the model

```
   var Time = new Marionette.Application();

  Time.addRegions({
      mainRegion: "#main-region"
  });

  TimeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
          time: "Now",
          milliseconds_since_epoch: 1234,
          date: "Today"
      },
      urlRoot: 'http://date.jsontest.com/'

  });
  var TodaysTime = new TimeModel();

  TimeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      template: "#template",
      model: TodaysTime,

      onRender: function () {
             TodaysTime.fetch({
                 success: function (apiTime) {
                  console.log(apiTime.attributes.time);
                  TodaysTime = apiTime;
              }
          });
      }

  });

  var timeView = new TimeView();
  Time.mainRegion.show(timeView);
  Time.start();
```

And then in my template I have this

```
<p><%- time %> <%- milliseconds_since_epoch %></p>
```

I get no errors and nothing is displaying but the `console.log(apiTime.attributes.time)` that is inside the function works

inside the console if i type this `TodaysTime.attributes.time` it also works
but if i try `<p><%- TodaysTime.attributes.time %> </p>` I get the default value `Now`

What is the proper way to display value from a model?

Github link to test https://github.com/nolawi/time-machine-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because you render the model before you fetch the data from the server. That's why you see the default values. You should use listeners on model, promises or callbacks. Here's how it could be fixed:

```
      ...
      var TodaysTime = new TimeModel();
      TodaysTime.fetch().done(function(){Time.mainRegion.show(timeView);});

      TimeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
          template: "#template",
          onRender: function() {
              console.log('rendered');
              TodaysTime.fetch({
                  success: function(apiTime) {
                      console.log(apiTime.attributes.time);
                  }

              });
          }

      });

      var timeView = new TimeView({
        model: TodaysTime
      });
      ...
```

**Edit after you comment:**
Well, it really depends on your case. Some move this logic in routes for example. You can just add *initialize* function (but remove *fetch* from *onRender* first) to you *ItemView*. Something like:

```
initialize: function () {
                this.model.on('sync', this.render, this);
                this.model.fetch({ reset: true, change: true });
                return this;
              }
```

Comment: Great now I know why! Is there a better way to do this. Should I not be fetching from the ItemView?

Comment: This is great thank you! it seems to be more organized!